# Problems with creating a new environment

Tags: environments

I need to create a new environment that works like:

```
\begin{explanation} 
Here starts the explanation ... 
 \end{explanation}
```

In the document it should look like:

> **Explanation.** *Here starts the explanation ...*

Still being relatively new to TeX I struggle to get the result I want. 
I started with

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx} 
\newenvironment{explanation}{\textbf{Explanation.} }{}
\begin{document}    
\end{document}
```

but I don't know how to continue. Does anyone know how to continue?

Comment: Add `\itshape` and remove the space after the closing brace of `\textbf{}`.

Comment: I changed it to 
`\newenvironment{explanation}{\textbf{Explanation.}}{\itshape}`, which is closer to what I want but the text (in this case: Here starts the explanation) is still not cursive.

I get what I want, when I use `\begin{explanation} \textit{Here …} \end{explanation}` but ideally I don't want to use `\textit{}`

Comment: you are putting `\itshape` at wrong location (at end of environment)

Comment: You probably want something more like `\newenvironment{pexplanation}{\par\textbf{Explanation. }\itshape\ignorespaces}{\par}`. But I guess things should be slightly more sophisticated. Have a look at `amsthm`.

Comment: Indeed. I'd suggest `\usepackage{amsthm}
\theoremstyle{plain}
\newtheorem*{explanation}{Explanation}`.

Comment: `\newenvironment{explanation}{\par\textbf{Explanation. }\itshape}{\par}`. That's what I was looking for. Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will want to start a new paragraph for your environment and you need an `\itshape`. You could try

```
\newenvironment{pexplanation}{\par\textbf{Explanation. }\itshape\ignorespaces}{\par}
```

But I'd rather suggest to use a theorem package like `amsthm`. Things are much easier there

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\usepackage{kantlipsum}% for the example text

% with amsthm
\usepackage{amsthm}
\theoremstyle{plain}
\newtheorem*{explanation}{Explanation}

% manually
\newenvironment{pexplanation}{\par\textbf{Explanation. }\itshape\ignorespaces}{\par}

\begin{document}    
\kant[1]
\begin{explanation}
Here starts the explanation ...
\end{explanation}
\kant[2]
\begin{pexplanation}
Here starts the explanation ...
\end{pexplanation}
\kant[3]
\end{document}
```

[image: screenshot of the MWE: The first **Explanation.** is shown in bold on a new line without indentation. The explanation is set off from the surrounding paragraphs by vertical space. The second **Explanation.** is indented like the beginning of a normal paragraph, it is not set off by vertical space.]

---

You can have your explanations counted with `amsthm` if you use

```
\newtheorem{explanation}{Explanation}
```

(without the star) instead of `\newtheorem*`.

If you use `pexplanation` you'll need more code

```
\newcounter{pexplanation}
\newenvironment{pexplanation}{%
  \par
  \refstepcounter{pexplanation}%
  \textbf{Explanation \thepexplanation. }%
  \itshape
  \ignorespaces}
{\par}
```

Comment: Is there a way to count the Explanations like

**Explanation 1.** ...
**Explanation 2.** …

Comment: @offline That is very easy with `amsthm`: just remove the `*` in `\newtheorem*`.